# Found a stale link in an answer to a locked question

Tags: support, suggested-edits

In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/102217/8896457

Please change non-working link:

> http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/completionlist.png

to:

> https://web.archive.org/web/20120626154941/http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/completionlist.png

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I don't see edit

Comment: Ah, right, because the post is locked. We don't alter historically locked posts. The post is *archived*, preserved in original form. It doesn't need fixing anymore.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, but the link is not working, why not just repair it? It will still be historical

Comment: As it's just an image, perhaps better to upload it again on imgur.

Comment: I don't see how this question is *off-topic*. The answer may be *no*, but a declined request does not an off-topic question make.

Comment: A long time ago we had a discussion about a moderator editing an outdated link in a locked post @MartijnPieters.  I can't find the link right now, but I definitely recall there being that discussion.  I think the ultimate action taken was that it *was* edited, but I'd respect that this not be edited now anyway since it doesn't feel like it needs to be.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: there was confusion at the start about why there was a request here at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The Meta Stack Exchange FAQ [states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) that if one notices a serious problem with a historically locked post, one should make a meta post. (Though it's only supposed to be done for *serious* issues; I don't know whether or not this qualifies as "serious".)

Comment: @gparyani: The FAQ elaborates on 'serious'. This one is not a serious issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Part of the answer is unavailable, thus the answer is not in its "archived, preserved original form" as you said. That can be serious issue for some. I think any argument is not going to change your mind. Is it possible that other moderators will look at this issue?